# Missing required module error

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am creating a framework "ABC" in Swift. I have integrated Objective C code using submodule "ABCPrivate" inside framework. I have set Import Paths for internal module.
When I use this framework in other applications it is referring to the same paths that i have set in Import Paths in Framework project.
Its working fine on machine in which its developed but not on other machines(as it is referring to same import paths for internal module).

Comment: How did you set the paths? Did you use relative or absolute paths?

Comment: Its relative path. Path is $(SRCROOT)/ABC/ProjectModule/"

Comment: same problem with me. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Instead of using module, I put Objective C code inside a framework and used that in swift project.